# Sum of factors of multiplication of different numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring, divisor-sum

> Given $N$ numbers $n_i$ such that $\forall i \le N,  n_i$ $\le10^9$, is there a method to calculate the sum of divisors of their product?

For example, given $\{11,15,17\}$ their product would is $2805$. The divisors of 2805 are $\{1,3,5,11,15,17,33,51,55,85,165,187,255,561,935,2805\}$, and the sum of those divisors (which is what I'm looking for) is $5184$.

I am a programmer and looking to implement this equation in my code. Tackling it with loops does work, but on large numbers it takes about 5 minutes to give a result!

Comment: How is 2 a divisor?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Comment: ohh, sorry about that! my bad. remove the 2

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to MatLab, you could use this `divisor(n)` function by Yash. From there, just call `sum` to get your total. For example:

```
>> sum(divisor(2805))
ans =
  5184
```